# How to get Ethereum dashboard up and running

Tags: private-blockchain

How to get the ethereum dashboard running, I have installed all the dependencies, following steps mentioned in https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/dashboard

I followed the steps mentioned,

> $ (cd dashboard/assets && npm install)
>
> $ (cd dashboard/assets && ./node_modules/.bin/flow-typed install)

When I do,

> go generate ./dashboard

I get the following error,

> running "go-bindata": exec: "go-bindata": executable file not found in $PATH

What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Hi there. Do you have Go installed on your system?

Comment: Yes, I have Go installed. I corrected my GOPATH and now it is exiting with exit status 2